# Understanding constraints of a racing line (curve).

Tags: curves, curvature

[This academic paper](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/64669/706825301-MIT.pdf) outlines various approaches to identifying the ideal racing line of an arbitrary race track.

[On page 10](https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/64669/706825301-MIT.pdf#page=10), the problem is formulated, and the idea is to minimize total lap time. Expressed as minimizing $\int \frac{1}{v} ds$ where $s$ is the curvilinear distance travelled along the track, and $v$ is the velocity of the car. It has the following constraints ($k$ is the curvature at a specific point).

[image]

My question is about the second constraint: $\int kds = \Delta \theta$ as it makes no sense to me. The paper describes the constraint as such:
[image]

Ultimately I have 3 main questions:

1. Why would $\theta$ be used to parameterize a curve and not something like a $t$ value with a point on the curve being defined as $(x(t),y(t))$?
2. How is $\theta$ defined? I.e. what is the angle based off of?
3. And finally, what is the point of this constraint?

I'm not sure if the constraints are paper-specific, or if there is some mathematical reasoning behind it.

Comment: Let $\theta$ is angle between tangent to track and fixed direction. Then $d\theta=\frac{ds}{r}=k\,ds$. Integration gives $\Delta \theta=\int k\, ds$. But I don't understand how it is related with picture from the paper. $\Delta \theta$ is turning angle. In case of track bounding convex region turning angle is increasing with distance and can be used to parameterize the distance.

Comment: @IvanKaznacheyeu Ah I see, so $\theta$ is not the angle of the "pie slice" for lack of better terms. But rather the change in the angle of the tangential vectors. The diagram is indeed very misleading. Though I still don't see the need for this constraint. I think a $t$ value would be better and easier to parameterize the curve.